# bash : cd : too many arguments

Tags: bash, cd, quoting

if i need to go to my directory named as"exception handling" then i write (cd exception handling) but it gives error too many arguments

Comment: Either put the file name in quotes or escape the spaces so that `bash` knows it's one string: `cd 'long file name'` or `cd long\ file\ name`. The problem is not unique to Ubuntu. If you were in a Windows command shell you'd have the same issue.

Comment: The problem is unique to bash 4.4; its implementation of "cd" is buggy.  The manual page bash(1) specifies that " Any  additional  arguments following dir are ignored."  The OP's command should go to directory "exception" and ignore "handling".  Instead it throws an error.  This is a bug.  I tried bash 4.2, where "cd" works correctly.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
cd "new folder"
```

or escape the space:

```
cd new\ folder
```

(That being said, `cd` does not open a file but changes the working directory.)

Comment: This is what I was looking for

Comment: Can this be saved in variable or alias? E.g. NF="new\ folder"; cd $NF