# "too many arguments" in VSC terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am having "cd: too many arguments" in VSC terminal when I try to run simple helloworld (in C). This is the code. I am using code runner to run my code inside VSC.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello World");
   return 0;
}
```

And this is the error:

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

Comment: Is this same to you problem?
[problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351933/bash-cd-too-many-arguments)

Comment: heh? That error doesn't come from the code you posted.

Comment: Hey,sorry for the misunderstanding. I fixed the problem. I changed my settings.json File.

Comment: There were 2 lines that causing for too many arguments in settings.json File. Erasing them solved the problem.

Comment: Hey @SilverShroud, do you mind sharing your fix, I'm trying to figure out what's going on with VS code too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Used this settings.json to fix the problem. And it worked.

```
{
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "http.proxySupport": "off"

}
```